# Geometric problem, differential equations

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the following problem:

Point B is any point on the curve and we pass through it the tangent that intersects the Y axis at point A. Let us denote the origin of the coordinate system by C. Determine the curve passing through the point (1,1) and satisfying the condition: the area of the triangle CAB is equal to 2.

How to draw it and calculate it?

[image]

The area of triangle ABC is:

$\frac{1}{2}$base$\times$height=$\frac{1}{2}$AC×BH=$\frac{1}{2}\vert(f(x_0)−x_0f′(x_0))x_0\vert=2$

Dropping the index 0, we have the differential equation:

$\frac{1}{2}\vert(f(x)−xf′(x))x\vert=2$  with initial condition f(1)=1

We can write it under the equivalent form:

$f(x)−xf′(x)=\pm\frac{4}{x}$

So

$f(x)=\pm\frac{2}{x}+Kx$
When I calculate K I have K is -1 and K=3. If I take $\pm$.

That's why I wrote two curves because I take the absolute value into account.

Comment: I know the formula for the tangent y-v = y '(u) (x-u). Your cue tells me nothing, since I don't know how to start this task.

Comment: I added a drawing but I don't know if it is correct.

Comment: Starting from $y-f(x_0)=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$ (which is not exactly what you have written) or equivalently $y=f'(x_0)x+(f(x_0)-x_0f'(x_0))$, can you express the coordinates of $A(0; ?)$ ? Then equate two expressions for the area of triangle $ABC$ which is equal to $\frac12 base \times height$ and as well equal to  $2$. This will give you a differential equation. Initial conditions will be provided by the fact that $(1,1)$ belongs to the curve, i.e., $f(1)=1$.

Comment: And the drawing is correct?

Comment: See the solution I jut gave. In fact, your drawing is partially correct for the vertical asymptote, But in fact, the curve will cross the $x$ axis and have a oblique asymptote afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can assume hereafter without loss of generality that $x>0$.

Let $y=f(x)$ be the cartesian equation of the unknown curve.

The equation of the tangent in $B(x_0,f(x_0)$ is

$$y-f(x_0)=f'(x_0)(x-x_0) \ \iff \ y=f'(x_0)x+(f(x_0)-x_0f'(x_0))$$

Setting $x=0$, one gets the coordinates of the intersection of the tangent with $y$ axis:

$$A(0  \ ; \ f(x_0)-x_0f'(x_0))$$

Let us call $H$ the projection of $B$ onto the $y$ axis.

The area of triangle $ABC$ is:

$$\frac12\text{base} \times \text{height}=\frac12\text{AC} \times \text{BH}=\frac12|f(x_0)-x_0f'(x_0))|x_0=2$$

Dropping index $0$, we get the differential equation for $f$:

$$\frac12|f(x)-xf'(x)|x=2 \ \ \text{with initial condition} \ f(1)=1$$

We can write it under the equivalent form:

$$|f(x)-xf'(x)|=\dfrac{4}{x},\tag{1}$$

giving rise to 2 differential equations:

$$\begin{cases}(DE_1):& \ \  f(x)-xf'(x)&=&\dfrac{4}{x}\\(DE_2):& \ \  f(x)-xf'(x)&=&-\dfrac{4}{x}\end{cases}$$

Let us consider $(DE_1)$. You can solve it

- either by using Laplace Transform if you happen to know it.
- or by using the ["method of variation of constants"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters) (see Appendix to this answer).
- or by using the following "astute" way:

Let us divide LHS and RHS of (1) by $-x^2$ giving:

$$\frac{f'(x)x-f(x)}{x^2}=\frac{-4}{x^3}$$

We recognize in the LHS and RHS a derivative:

$$\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)^{\prime}=2\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^{\prime}$$

giving

$$\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)=2\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)+K$$

for some constant $K$. Otherwise said:

$$f(x)=\frac{2}{x}+Kx\tag{2}$$

As $f(1)=1$, using (2), we get by replacing $x$ by $1$:

$$1=2+K \ \implies \ K=-1$$

Let us represent the curve of $f$ defined by :

$$f(x)=\frac{2}{x}-x\tag{3}$$

on Fig. 1 (dark blue with its asymptotes in light blue). You will see there two examples of triangles $ABC$ (in red and in magenta), for which you can check that their area is indeed $2$.

A similar process can be applied to $(DE_2)$ finally giving:

$$f(x)=3x-\dfrac{2}{x}\tag{4}$$

(see Fig. 2). I had overlooked this second solution that the asker has put in evidence afterwards.

[image]

*Fig. 1: solution of $(DE_1)$ (equation (3)) with two examples of triangle ABC (red and magenta) with area $2$.*

[image]

*Fig. 2: Solution of $(DE_2)$ (equation (4)) with, as well, two examples of triangle ABC (red and magenta) .*

**Appendix:** Differential equation $(DE_1)$ can be solved by the method of variation of constants in this way:

Firstly, solve equ. (1) with RHS set to $0$. One obtains $y=cx$.

Now consider constant $c$ as an unknown function $c(x)$, meaning that one  looks for a solution of the form

$$f(x)=c(x)x\tag{3}$$

to the original diff. equation (1), giving;

$$c(x)x-x(c(x)x)'=\dfrac{4}{x}$$

$$\iff c(x)x-x(c'(x)x+c(x)1)=\dfrac{4}{x}$$

$$\iff -x^2c'(x)=\dfrac{4}{x} \iff c'(x)=-\dfrac{4}{x^3}\tag{4}$$

Integrating (4), we get $c(x)=\dfrac{2}{x^2}+K.$

Therefore, using (3), the solution of (1) is:

$$f(x)=c(x)x=\dfrac{2}{x}+Kx \tag{5}$$

as found before.

Comment: I have $\frac{1}{2}\text{base} \times \text{height}=\frac{1}{2}\vert\text{AC} \vert\times \vert\text{BH}\vert=\vert\frac{1}{2}(f(x_0)-x_0f'(x_0))x_0\vert=2$ so $(f(x_0)-x_0f'(x_0))x_0=\pm4$

Comment: So I understand that when I considered the second option, it is correct, so I have a curve of the form $ y = \frac{2}{x} -x $ and $ y = 3x- \frac{2}{x} $. You helped me a lot, now I understand what the task is about, but I wanted to make sure that I can take the second branch into account.

Comment: Thanks to you, I learned about other possibilities for solving such tasks.

Comment: Thank you for your help and for explaining it to me.